# Does anyone know of a good SEAM 3 example in production?

Tags: seam, production, seam3

I'm interested in seeing SEAM 3's capabilities in a production environment, but have yet to come across any SEAM 3 sites in production.  Even the official seam site's [seam in production](http://sfwk.org/Community/SeamInProduction) section only features SEAM 1 & 2 sites.

Does anyone know of any examples of SEAM3 in production?

Answer (score -1):

You can see a good overview from MIklos Piklos in this post : https://community.jboss.org/thread/178490?start=15&tstart=0.

I hope that could help you

Comment: I'm sorry, they don't have example on this link. He only explain his project but he not post example.